# NodeJS application and HTTPS with Certificate

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate

I'd like to ask you for advice. I'm not familiar with HTTPS and certificates. I have my own small application that works on Nodejs.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chatwidgethttps",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/ index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

npm start and my app is working on https://localhost:3333. I put this URL to the external LiveChat platform (under https) because my app should work as a live chat widget. All data have to be secured (all the data is secret)

My question is what's the best approach in this case - do I need a self signed certificate? 
will everyone who wants to use my application have to install a certificate? If yes - how? 
how to make the certificate install automatically?

So far I've tried something like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')
const path = require('path')

const app = express();
const directoryToServe = 'client'
const port = 3333

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', directoryToServe)))

const httpsOptions = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.crt')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.key'))
};

https.createServer(httpsOptions,app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started')
});
```

One of the hundreds of the tutorials says that after all I have to install my public server.crt certificate on the browser but it doesn't work - on the browser I still see the red text NOT SECURE. On Firefox or IE is my app completely invisible - I get the message:

> This site is not secure
>
> This might mean that someone’s trying to fool you or steal any info
>   you send to the server. You should close this site immediately.

Thank You very much in advance for all your tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please pay a visit to [Let's Encrypt](https://certbot.eff.org/). It's gives you free signed certificates, with certbot which will auto-renew the certificates when expired.
Also i would not recommend serving certificates from Express application, as it would slow down the performance of the application drastically. So consider using [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/), which is a reverse proxy load balancer that can also serve certificates needed by HTTPS.

Comment: May I somehow use a free certificate? Is it possible with a free certificate to have a secured webpage (green) immedately? At the start? Without installing manually a certificate?

Comment: @matley yes it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

I've tested my https app locally and had problems with not secure connection. But the answer is simple - 
all we have to do is upload our applications to the https server which should already have some certificates.